# How can I make a reusable Select component which implements ControlValueAcessor?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my first attempt at a reusable component.

Can you explain with best practices how can I make this example into a reusable component implementing `ControlValueAcessor`?

```html
<div class="componentName">
    <label for="months">Your label</label>
    <select name="months">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">January</option>
        <option value="1">February</option>
        <option value="2">March</option>
    </select>
    <p>There is my text </p>
</div>
```

Comment: what is controlValueAcessor in your code? what is your interface? you can edit your post and add them.

Comment: the select option is a controlvalueacessor to send data

Comment: Is your aim to implement `ControlValueAccessor` for this component? If not what is it? Your question is not clear.

Comment: i wanna implement controlvalueaccesor for this component select and make it reusable help me please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to clarify what your final goal is and add any relevant information about your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly make your component generic**

Add inputs for generic values:

```
@Input() public label: string;
@Input() public options: {value: number, description: string}[];
@Input() public text: string;
```

Update your template to use those inputs:

```
<div class="componentName">
    <label for="months">{{ label }}</label>
    <select name="months">
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">{{ option.description }}</option>
    </select>
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
</div>
```

**Now implement ControlValueAccessor**

We use `ngModel` and `ngModelChange` to write and read values to the select.

```
 <select name="months" [ngModel]="selectedIndex" 
 ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
```

In the template we implement `ControlValueAccessor` with some boiler plate

```
  public onChange = (_: any) => {};
  public onTouched = () => {};

  public registerOnChange(fn): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
```

Then in order to write values (ie: selected index) to the select from the form model, we create a suitable `writeValue` function:

```
 public writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.selectedIndex = value;
 }
```

And to read values from the select and write them to the form model we call `onChange` (and `OnTouched` for completeness):

```
 valueChanged(value: any) {
    this.onChange(value);
    this.onTouched();
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gqsdv8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-select.component.ts

Answer (score -1):

first you can set your data in an array then use *ngFor directive
interface file :
 `export interface IMonth{   id: number,   name: string, };`

ts file:

```
 let months:IMonth[]; 

months:IMonth =[{ id: 1, name: 'February' },
{ id: 2, name: 'March' }]; 

    <select name="months">
            <option value ="month.id"  *ngFor="month of months" >{{month.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: thank you how can i make it reusable and add controlvalue acessor?

Comment: //interface:
----
`export interface IMonth{
  id: number,
  name: string,
}

let months:IMonth[];
months =[{ id: 1, name: 'February' },
                  { id: 2, name: 'March' }];
`
......

Comment: we d'ont use input and output in reusable(shared) component ?

Comment: use input for send or receive data between child and parent or its better to say between components...